# Does there exist a differentiable function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ whose zeros are a line?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, roots

Suppose we are given a line in $\mathbb R^3$.  Is there a differentiable function, $f$, from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ such that the solutions to $f(\vec{x})=0$ are precisely the points on the line?

I would like to be able to describe a line using the zeros of a single function rather than using a parametrization.

EDIT: I deleted a false claim about not being able to use a polynomial.

Comment: How about $f(x) =$ the square of the (perpendicular) distance from $x$ to the line?

Comment: @JonathanZ:  I think that works.  I had in mind something much more complicated but couldn’t see why it would be differentiable.  Is the square necessary?  It seems to me just using the distance to the line would work.

Comment: Yup, the square is to keep it differentiable. If you use the distance then restricting  yourself to a line perpendicular to your given line your function looks like the absolute value.

Comment: Actually, every closed subset of $R^n$ is the zero level set of a smooth function.

Comment: @Moishe:  I did not know that.  Thank you for telling me this.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: That's a nice fact. I wasn't sure if the OP wanted a general theorem of s very specific answer to their very specific question. So I just answered the specific version.

Comment: In dimension 2 you can use a signed distance to the line to avoid the square, i dont think this is available in dimension 3

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: Of course, in this special case your solution is optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume your line is given by

$$\vec L(t) = \vec p + t\vec v$$

where $||\vec v || = 1$, then for any point $\vec x $, the point on $\vec L$ that is closest to $\vec x$  (let's call it $proj(\vec x) $) is given by

$$proj( \vec x ) = \vec p + ((\vec x - \vec p)\cdot\vec v) v.$$

Then you can let

$$f(\vec x) = ||\vec x - proj(\vec x)||^2.$$

Incidentally, you can write this out explicitly and see that it is differentiable. In fact, it should be a quadratic in the components of $\vec x$. Which means either I made a mistake, or your statement that "I know there are no polynomials with this property" has a problem. I'm not yet 100% sure which -- can you say why you believe that to be so?

Comment: Without loss of generality assume the line goes through the origin.  If it’s the zero set of a polynomial f then R[x,y,z]/(f) would have dimension 1 but by Krull Principle Ideal Theorem it can’t be 1.

Comment: This is the second time someone has laid the Krull PIT on me. I've never seen it before and now I have to go read up on it! :-) But can you resolve the apparent contradiction? Because I can't and now I'm concerned I've got a mistake in my answer.

Comment: I might be wrong on my algebraic geometry since we aren’t working over an algebraically closed field.  The line is an affine variety of dimension 1.  So the coordinate ring has dimension 1.  This means the ideal of the variety has height 2.  The Krull PIT says that if the ideal is generated by a single element then the height is at most 1.

Comment: My reasoning must be faulty since we aren’t using an algebraically closed field.  The zero set of x^2+y^2 is the z-axis in R^3.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2$. The solutions of $f(x,y,z)=0$ are the $z$ axis. Then just compose with an affine transformation that sends your line to the $z$ axis and you're done.